# Modifying a numpy array inside a function?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pass-by-reference

I have a problem with the simple program below :

```
def my_function(my_array = np.zeros(0)):
    my_array = [1, 2, 3]

my_array = np.zeros(0)
my_function(my_array)
print my_array
```

It prints an empty array as if `my_array` was passed by copy and not by reference inside the function. How to correct that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`np.zeros(0)` gives you an empty numpy array. The reference inside your function now points to a new Python list but you haven't actually modified your empty numpy array, so that's still what you're printing out.

Recommend to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/553404) to clear up some concepts.

Comment: I do not understand why when I print the array inside the function it works well, but not outside...

Comment: You should read the first answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Answer (score 17):

The pass-by-reference model is more of a pass-by-value of a pointer.  So inside your my_function you have a copy of a pointer to your original my_array.  If you were to use that pointer to manipulate the inputed array directly that would make a change, but a re-assignment of the copied pointer won't affect the original array.

As an example:

```
def my_func(a):
    a[1] = 2.0

ar = np.zeros(4)
my_func(ar)
print ar
```

The above code will change the internal value of ar.

Answer (score 9):

You can use slice assignment here just like you would a list:

```
def func(my_array):
    my_array[:3] = [1,2,3]
```

Note that this still requires that `my_array` has at least 3 elements in it ... Example usage:

```
>>> def func(my_array):
...     my_array[:3] = [1,2,3]
... 
>>> a = np.zeros(4)
>>> a
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
>>> func(a)
>>> a
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  0.])
```

The thing you're missing is how python deals with references.  When you enter `my_function`, you have a reference to the original ndarray object bound to the name `my_array`.  However, as soon as you *assign* something new to that name, you lose your original reference and replace it with a reference to a new object (in this case, a list).

Note that having a default argument which is a mutable object can often [lead to surprises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: I wonder if there's a neat way to avoid the `:3`. If the input array had, say, ten elements, then this code would not do what I suspect the OP would expect from his code.

Comment: This doesn't actually work - try `a = np.zeros(0)`
and `a[:3] = [1,2,3]`

Comment: @MrE -- Sure.  I suppose I'm assuming that OP is actually going to pass in an argument that is large enough to handle the RHS in the calculation.